# Switch sum column in SUMIF formula in case criteria is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
   |      A          B           C          D       |    E   |       F                G
---|------------------------------------------------|--------|------------------------------     
1  |  SALES-ORIGINAL                                |        |   SALES-ADJUSTED   
2  |  Product       quarter     type      volume    |        |   Product            volume
3  |  Product_A     Q1          n          800      |        |   Product_B            480
4  |  Product_A     Q2          n          900      |        |   Product_D            250
5  |  Product_B     Q1          t          400      |        |   Product_E            760
6  |  Product_C     Q1          n          300      |        |  
7  |  Product_D     Q1          t          200      |        |  
8  |  Product_D     Q2          t          800      |        |  
9  |  Product_E     Q2          t          600      |        |  
10 |  Prodcut_F     Q1          n          700      |        |  
11 |                                                |        |
---|------------------------------------------------|--------|---------------------------------
12 |                                                |        | 
13 |                Q1          Q2                  |        |
14 |   Sales       2.530     1.910                  |        |
15 |                                                |        |
16 |                                                |        |
```

---

In the above Excel sheet I have two different tables called `SALES-ORIGINAL` and `SALES-ADJUSTED`. 
In `Row 14` I want to display the `sum` of the sales in quarter `Q1` and `Q2` according to `Column D` and `Column B`.

---

However, for products  with `type` `t` in `Column C` I the sales volume in `Column G` should be used and **not** the one from `Column D`. 
The calculation is the following:

```
B14 = 800 + 480 + 300 + 250 + 700
C14 = 900 + 250 + 760
```

---

Is there a `SUMIF` function that can switch between **two** `SUM columns` in case a certain criteria is met? 
*(In the example the formula would use the values in Column G instead of Column D if a product is assigned to type t)*

Comment: What are your restrictions? Do you need a single formula? Can we add columns? Are there many products so you should have something more dynamic, of are they just a few?

Comment: Use a helper column where if col C is t then it is a 1. Then sumproduct().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all new/old Excel version and shorter formula.

In `B15` enter formula and copied right to `C15` :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B3:$B10=B$14)*(($C3:$C10="t")*SUMIF($F3:$F5,$A3:$A10,$G3:$G5)+($C3:$C10="n")*$D3:$D10))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the following formula uses XLOOKUP, you need Office 365

Put this Formula in B15

English Verion:
`=SUMIFS($D$3:$D$10,$B$3:$B$10,B$14,$C$3:$C$10,'<>t')+SUMPRODUCT(--($B$3:$B$10=B$14)*--($C$3:$C$10='t')*XLOOKUP($A$3:$A$10,$F$3:$F$5,$G$3:$G$5,0))`

German Version:
`=SUMMEWENNS($D$3:$D$10;$B$3:$B$10;B$14;$C$3:$C$10;"<>t")+SUMMENPRODUKT(--($B$3:$B$10=B$14)*--($C$3:$C$10="t")*XVERWEIS($A$3:$A$10;$F$3:$F$5;$G$3:$G$5;0))`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have O365, you can use the following formula:

Note that I converted the data to **Tables** and am using structured references. This will make it much simpler if the data table changes in size, as the references will auto adjust:

```
    H14: =SUMIFS(Original[[volume]:[volume]],Original[[quarter]:[quarter]],B13,Original[[type]:[type]],"<>t")+
SUM(SUMIF(Adjusted[[Product]:[Product]], INDEX(Original[[Product]:[Product]],AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((Original[[quarter]:[quarter]]=B13)*(Original[[type]:[type]]="t"))*ROW(Original),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTIFS(Original[[quarter]:[quarter]],B13,Original[[type]:[type]],"t"))))-ROW(Adjusted[#Headers])),Adjusted[[volume]:[volume]]))
```

Fill right as needed

[image]

*If you have O365, you can use:

```
=SUM(FILTER(Original[[volume]:[volume]],(Original[[quarter]:[quarter]]=B13)*(Original[[type]:[type]]<>"t")),
XLOOKUP(FILTER(Original[[Product]:[Product]],(Original[[quarter]:[quarter]]=B13)*(Original[[type]:[type]]="t")),Adjusted[[Product]:[Product]],Adjusted[[volume]:[volume]]))
```